# White Label Magento - Community Edition

Tags: labels

Is there a white label plan I can purchase from Magento so I re-sell Magento Community sites under my own company name?

Answer (score 1):

No

Especially not now that Adobe own Magento.

Not sure whether this is the answer you are expecting or not.